# Overflow cutting up results (image attached)

Tags: css, list, overflow, hidden

[image]

The section of "results" on the left is what's currently happening. The section on the right I what I want to happen to the results. When the group of results seem to big for the container the result at the bottom of the container show hide itself. I've been searching all over the web for CSS fixes, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Are the child elements a uniform height as you've drawn them? If so, and if you must use a particular container height, a mask at the bottom (or padding) could conceal partial child elements. 

Generally, CSS does not allow for this type of logic. That's where jQuery comes in handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a trick including the use of `columns` which may not be fully supported.

http://jsfiddle.net/szGVu/

```
#holder{
  columns: 110px;
  -webkit-columns: 110px;
  -moz-columns: 110px;

  height: 300px;
  width: 110px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.child{
  margin: 5px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: A good solution for any browser but IE < 10.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348061/how-to-display-css3-columns-on-ie