# Column tag of css is not working in internet explorer

Tags: css

```
.threeColulmn{
    columns:170px 3;
    -webkit-columns:170px 3; 
    -moz-columns:170px 3; 
}
```

I am trying to dividing div into three columns it works porperly in mozila and chrome but in internet explorer its not working. kindly give me some solution.

Comment: Probably duplicate question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348061/how-to-display-css3-columns-on-ie

Answer (score 0):

[caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/) will show you support for selectors from CSS 3. http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn is what you're looking for.

Internet Explorer doesn't support columns in version 9. Version 10 ought to work. If you need support for version 9, you're going to need a shiv to provide the functionality.

https://github.com/BetleyWhitehorne/CSS3MultiColumn is recommended by [Modernizer](http://modernizr.com/)